# Any Easy way to make Eyelashes?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to create eyelashes for my character and have tried a few tutorials, yet most are hard to follow, are there any ways to do this with minimal use of the particle system.

Comment: There are many ways to make eyelashes, however some require more manual work than others. Particles are a quick way of making "a bunch" of an object, with easy settings to make each "duplicate" slightly different if desired (ex: varying hair length). Given that an entire category of the particle system is dedicated to hair, you might want to reconsider using it for eyelashes, as it's probably the easiest way. Is there something specific that's giving you trouble? I can walk you through the process if necessary.

Comment: I get stuck when trying to mirror changes over from one side to another. A video I tried says to delete one side of the particles and mirror it, yet on my file it won't mirror.

Comment: Do you mind sharing a link to the video? I could probably assist better if I knew the process they're using.

Comment: https://youtu.be/6aQwB_HE3oY

Comment: https://youtu.be/6aQwB_HE3oY?t=323 5:23

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what the mirroring's all about - he's using a lot of modifiers, and it looks like the whole model is mirrored itself. That's a pretty complex video - a lot going on really fast. I'll have to take a while to backtrack his steps to figure out where things are going wrong. Unfortunately, I don't have the time at the moment. I'll look into it later on tonight when I have some time, and I'll try to provide a detailed answer. I'll also upvote in case someone else can answer in the meantime.

Comment: The most common and easy way to make eyelashes are by using a eyelash texture with alpha on a plane. I'm not a character artist or so but I have seen the same in a lot of characters even the one in Daz Studio uses the same technique.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help so far.